# Add foreign key constraint to existing column, while auto-generating the key name?

Tags: postgresql

If I already created some tables with columns, like this:

```
create table "Sender"(
    "id" varchar not null unique
);

create table "Message"(
    "sender" varchar not null
);

-- Oops! The "sender" column should reference the "id" in "Sender" table!
```

But then I realise one of the columns should actually have a foreign key constraint (reference). Is there a way to add this foreign key constraint **without** having to "manually" enter a new name for it?

Something along the lines of:

```
alter table "Message" alter column "sender" set references "Sender"("id");
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Posting it here because the postgres docs doesn't actually  have this example.

```
alter table "Message" add foreign key ("sender") references "Sender"("id");
```

This will add a foreign key constraint named "Message_sender_fkey". Enjoy

**EDIT**

I find myself having to use this when I forgot to add cascading

```
alter table "Message"
drop constraint "Message_sender_fkey",
add foreign key ("sender") references "Sender"("id") on delete cascade;
```